# How can i continuously send requests after speech_event_type: END_OF_SINGLE_UTTERANCE Google Speech cloud Java

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-speech-api

I know that google cloud speech API (recognize) is limited to 65 seconds, but i assume that is per request and only a limitation if your speak is actually longer than that.

So, assume i just want some commands translations from the microphone and do a request to google speech.I add the model command_and_search and set setSingleUtterance(true) to config.

Below code send one request and print the results but i fail to understand how i can spawn new request for the next commands..like "help"...."right"...etc

```
import com.google.api.gax.rpc.ClientStream;
import com.google.api.gax.rpc.ResponseObserver;
import com.google.api.gax.rpc.StreamController;
import com.google.cloud.speech.v1p1beta1.*;
import com.google.protobuf.ByteString;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.DataLine;
import javax.sound.sampled.TargetDataLine;


public class App {


public static void AskGoogle (ClientStream<StreamingRecognizeRequest> c,byte[]  b ) {

    StreamingRecognizeRequest request =
            StreamingRecognizeRequest.newBuilder()
                    .setAudioContent(ByteString.copyFrom(b))
                    .build();

    c.send(request);
    return;

}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Target data line
    TargetDataLine line = null;
    AudioInputStream audio = null;

    // Capture Microphone Audio Data
    try {

        // Signed PCM AudioFormat with 16kHz, 16 bit sample size, mono
        int sampleRate = 16000;
        AudioFormat format = new AudioFormat(sampleRate, 16, 1, true, false);
        DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, format);

        // Check if Microphone is Supported
        if (!AudioSystem.isLineSupported(info)) {
            System.out.println("Line not supported");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        // Get the target data line
        line = (TargetDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
        line.open(format);
        line.start();

        // Audio Input Stream
        audio = new AudioInputStream(line);

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }


    // Send audio from Microphone to Google Servers and return Text
    try (SpeechClient client = SpeechClient.create()) {

        ResponseObserver<StreamingRecognizeResponse> responseObserver =
                new ResponseObserver<StreamingRecognizeResponse>() {

                    public void onStart(StreamController controller) {
                        // do nothing
                    }

                    public void onResponse(StreamingRecognizeResponse response) {

                        System.out.println(response);


                    }

                    public void onComplete() {
                    }

                    public void onError(Throwable t) {
                        System.out.println(t);
                    }
                };

        ClientStream<StreamingRecognizeRequest> clientStream =
                client.streamingRecognizeCallable().splitCall(responseObserver);

        RecognitionConfig recConfig =
                RecognitionConfig.newBuilder()
                        .setEncoding(RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.LINEAR16)
                        .setLanguageCode("sv-SE")
                        .setSampleRateHertz(16000)
                        .setModel("command_and_search")
                        .build();
        StreamingRecognitionConfig config =
                StreamingRecognitionConfig.newBuilder().setConfig(recConfig).setSingleUtterance(true).build();

        StreamingRecognizeRequest request =
                StreamingRecognizeRequest.newBuilder()
                        .setStreamingConfig(config)
                        .build(); // The first request in a streaming call has to be a config

        clientStream.send(request);

        while (true) {
            byte[] data = new byte[100];
            try {
                audio.read(data);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }

            AskGoogle(clientStream,data);


        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

 }

}
```

Comment: what errors is are you getting? what are you trying to do? 

See here [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) good questions in SO

Comment: I am not getting any errors at all. The code above works. I just dont know any good pattern to renew the request in the onResponse method, to send yet another 100 bytes of audio stream..which is my question. Mabey you can give some insight to that ?

Answer (score 2):

For whatever reason the question gets downvoted i actually found a solution to my problem to keep sending more request to speech api after the first transcription comes back in the OnResponse method (code above). Simply wrap everything from the try capture the mic block to request a new config with the speech client into a method like the above AskGoogle() and call it again when endpointerType "END_OF_UTTERANCE" in StreamingRecognizeResponse in OnResponse comes in.